# C# Marshalling a Double Wrapper Struct - Why Does Double Behave Strangely?

Tags: c#, struct, double, interop, marshalling

I'm writing a wrapper for a dynamic link library implemented in C.

Many of the functions return what are essentially standard, unmanaged, blittable types like `int`, `long long`, and `double`. To differentiate the values returned from the library I wanted to write some simple `struct`s to wrap these basic types and mark the imported functions as returning those types.

(This also had the added bonus of allowing me to implement the boolean type with `int` so it could be 4 bytes wide and thus match up with the 4-byte value the library was returning.)

To begin with all was going well, I had `LibraryBoolean`, `LibraryInteger` and `LibraryLong` all working fine, and then I got to `LibraryDouble`...

```cs
public struct LibraryDouble
{
    private double value;

    public LibraryDouble(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator LibraryDouble(double value)
    {
        return new LibraryDouble(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator double(LibraryDouble number)
    {
        return number.value;
    }
}
```

```cs
[DllImport("Library.dll", EntryPoint = "get_double_value", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern LibraryDouble get_double_value([In] int index);
```

Suddenly the value being returned was `4.94065645841247E-324` every time.

Vexingly I discovered that returning a plain `double` behaves as intended and that the strange behaviour is a result of me having a wrapper struct. Yet none of the other wrapper structs I've used have exhibited similar behaviour, it seems to be something unique to double.

Obviously, I could circumvent this problem by writing a wrapper function...

```cs
public static LibraryDouble get_double_value([In] int index)
{
    return _get_double_value(index);
}

[DllImport("Library.dll", EntryPoint = "get_double_value", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern double _get_double_value([In] int index);
```

But I'd like to know precisely why there seems to be a problem with `double` specifically when none of the other types seem to exhibit this problem.

**Why am I seeing this strange behaviour?**

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mre]?

Comment: That's the Epsilon value, perhaps you are stringifying it without rounding, whereas the other code calls `ToString` differently? "To differentiate the values returned from the library I wanted to write some simple structs to wrap these basic types" I don't get why you would want to do this. What's wrong with just returning the value itself?

Comment: @Charlieface "What's wrong with just returning the value itself?" Because different versions of the library might use different values. It might be `double` on one version and `float` on another. It's _far_ easier to change the internal representation of `LibraryNumber` from `double` to `float` than it is to go through a sea of code containing `double` or `float` and work out which ones are actually related to use of the library and thus have to be changed. If C# had the equivalent of `typedef` I'd be using that instead.

Comment: @GuruStron The user-side minimal example is just `Console.WriteLine(Library.get_double_value(0));` with the definitions of `get_double_value` and `LibraryNumber` that I've already provided. I can't reproduce the `.dll` side because I don't know how to go about writing/compiling a `.dll` and I can't provide the one I've been using because I don't have permission to publish it. If I knew of a function from a commonly-used library like one of the Win32 `.dll`s that returned `double` or `float` I could likely use that as an example.